# Return different kinds of iterators in flat_map

Tags: rust, iterator

In the following snippet of code, Rust complains that the return types do not match.

```rust
let line = String::new();    // assume string has content
let line: String = line.bytes()
    .flat_map(|b| {
        if b > 0x7F {
            format!("M-{}", char::from(b - 0x7F)).bytes()
        }
        else {
            [b].into_iter()    // error happens here
        }
    })
    .map(|b| { char::from(b) })
    .collect();
```

The error is the following:

> `if` and `else` have incompatible types
> expected type `std::str::Bytes<'_>`
> found struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>`

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/returning-different-kinds-of-iterators-in-flat-map/53634/2?u=dancojocaru2000).

The easiest solution is to use the [either](https://lib.rs/crates/either) crate.